# Finding the synonyms for words in wordnet

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wordnet

I try to use Wordnet as a thesarus, so I have a list of words and I need to collect for every word its synonyms. I tried this

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
for i,j in enumerate(wn.synsets('dog')):
    print (j.lemma_names)
```

This code gives the following output

```
<bound method Synset.lemma_names of Synset('dog.n.01')>
<bound method Synset.lemma_names of Synset('frump.n.01')>
<bound method Synset.lemma_names of Synset('dog.n.03')>
<bound method Synset.lemma_names of Synset('cad.n.01')>
<bound method Synset.lemma_names of Synset('frank.n.02')>
<bound method Synset.lemma_names of Synset('pawl.n.01')>
<bound method Synset.lemma_names of Synset('andiron.n.01')>
<bound method Synset.lemma_names of Synset('chase.v.01')>
```

But I want to collect in a list only the synonyms, so the output will be like this

['frump', 'cad', 'frank', 'pawl', 'andiron', 'chase']

Comment: What happens if you change the last line `print (j.lemma_names)` to `print (j.lemma_names())` ?

Answer (score 0):

As your output indicates, *lemma_names* is a method rather than a property. Blow code works as you expected:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
result = [st.lemma_names()[0] for st in wn.synsets('dog')]
print(result)
```

The output is:

```
[u'dog', u'frump', u'dog', u'cad', u'frank', u'pawl', u'andiron', u'chase']
```

Please note that the items in the list are of Unicode string. This is why you see the leading *u* in the output.